# ${env.JAVA_HOME} not found - Ant

Tags: ant, environment-variables, java-home

In my build.xml file, I have these lines:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo message="JAVA_HOME is set to = ${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
```

On some machine, this would print

```
"JAVA_HOME is set to = /usr/jdk1.6"
```

But on some others, it would print this

```
"JAVA_HOME is set to = ${env.JAVA_HOME}"
```

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The message tells you that Ant was not able to resolve the property `env.JAVA_HOME`; this means that the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` was not set in that machine.

Comment: If JAVA_HOME is not set, then how was it possible for the project to be built? (It's a Java project)

Comment: Ant does not require you to set `JAVA_HOME` (as you may have figured out because you were able to execute your build file even on machines where `JAVA_HOME` was not set)

Answer (score 9):

You can usually find on your system (if you're Unix) where the actual `ant` command lives by doing either `which ant` or `type ant`. If you look at that location, you will usually see that it's a link to the actual `ant` command under the `$ANT_HOME` directory.

Take a look at this script. Much of it is just trying to determine exactly where `$ANT_HOME` and `$JAVA_HOME` reside if these are not set by default in the environment.

What you don't see in the `ant` shell script is:

```
 EXPORT JAVA_HOME
```

So, even though `$JAVA_HOME` is set inside the `ant` script, it is never exported into the environment (unless someone has modified the `ant` shell script`. If an environment variable is not exported, it is unavailable to child processes -- like the`java`child process running your`ant` process.

Thus, if you are on a machine where `$JAVA_HOME` isn't set before `ant` is executed, it won't be available in your build script.

However, both Ant and Java (because Ant is a Java process) setup a whole slew of default properties that you can use. When Ant executes it sets it's [own built in properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#built-in-props) that include things like `${ant.home}`. And, when Java is executed, Java also sets up a complete list of [Java Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) like `${java.home}`.

So, if you really need to know where your JAVA_HOME directory is located, use the property `${java.home}` and not depend upon the environment variable `$JAVA_HOME`.

If you'd like to get a list of these properties, run the following Ant build file:

```
<project>
    <echoproperties/>
</project>
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer.. as it contains an answer to what the OP was  looking for...

Comment: well, this is just wrong. `${java.home}` is certainly not telling where JAVA_HOME is, only the environment variable will tell that. `${java.home}` will tell where JRE used in the execution is, which is a different thing.