# Can't get property values from ${env} in Apache Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have the following Ant target to show the value of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable:

```xml
<target name="show-java-home">
    <echo message="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
</target>
```

However, I get the following result:

```
show-java-home:
     [echo] ${env.JAVA_HOME}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 292 milliseconds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [${env.JAVA\_HOME} not found - Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571595/env-java-home-not-found-ant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<property environment="env"/>

<target name="show-java-home">
   <echo message="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
</target>
```

more info here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right.

This Ant console output tells you that `%JAVA_HOME%` simply isn't defined:

```
show-java-home:
     [echo] ${env.JAVA_HOME}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but `JAVA_HOME` is defined. And, as Alécio Carvalho answered, I forgot `<property environment="env"/>`.